# See process ran by conhost.exe

Tags: windows

Is it possible to see what process/command is ran by conhost.exe (command prompt) on Windows?

I have a batch file with a `java -jar ...` command in it that I run from Task Scheduler. In Task Manager it shows up as a `conhost.exe` process. The problem is when I "End" the task it does not stop the `conhost.exe` created by that task. I have to identify the right one and end it. But how do I reliably do it?

I am novice to system admin and apologize for any rookie mistakes. I tried searching for this, but did not get anything. I am coming from mostly Linux development to Windows. You can almost always see what command is ran from shell since shell is a parent to it, so I was kind of hoping for something similar on Windows. Thanks in advance.

Note: this may not look like a server problem, but it is a dev Win2012 server.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some more research for the sake of comleteness I found a fantastic set of tools for Windows: Sysinternals at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb545021.aspx. It has ProcessExplorer that shows all information about processes and if you run a bat file it also shows that under cmd.exe process. Things like that. No install needed for it.

Also, after poking around in Task Manager, I realized that if you add a column that shows "Command line" you can see information about what's running. It is not as comprehensive as ProcessExplorer, but still a good start.

Hopefully, it helps someone with the same question in the future.